# Cannot set CurrentCell focus to first editable column in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to select programatically the first editable column of a datagridview and cannot.

Column 0 and 1 are hidden.  Column 2 is read-only showing line number.  Columns 3 and on are editable.

If I do this:

```
grd.CurrentCell = grd.Rows[x].Cells[2];
```

The computer actually beeps and selects the first read-only column instead of selecting the first editable column.

If I do this:

```
grd.CurrentCell = grd.Rows[x].Cells[3];
```

It selects (focus) the third visible column (The second editable column) correctly. I cannot select the second visible column (the first editable column). What am I doing wrong?

To answer the question of when I am selecting the column, it is during the last tab event of the previous row.  I have a class to do this which inherits DataGridView.  Here is the relevant code in that class:

...

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
        {

            switch (keyData)
            {
                case Keys.Tab:
                    // Check if the tab key was pressed in the last column/row
                    if (currentCol == this.ColumnCount - 1 && currentRow == this.RowCount - 1)
                    {
                        LastTabReachedEventArgs ev = new LastTabReachedEventArgs();
                        ev.currentCol = currentCol;
                        ev.currentRow = currentRow;
                        OnLastTabReached(this, ev);
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case Keys.Enter:
                    // nothing to do
                    break;
            }
            return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);

        }
```

As you can see, the last column raises the OnLastTabReached which is handled in my form to select the first editable column of the next record.  Which fails:

```
 private void grd_LastTabReachedEvent(object sender, LastTabReachedEventArgs e)
        {

    grd.CurrentCell = grd.Rows[x].Cells[2];
}
```

But works if I select any additional columns:

```
 private void grd_LastTabReachedEvent(object sender, LastTabReachedEventArgs e)
        {
     grd.CurrentCell = grd.Rows[x].Cells[3];
}
```

I check the settings for the editable columns and they all have the same settings for a DataGridViewCell.

Thanks Before Hand

**Update #1**

Something is really strange.  I tried using the name of the grid cell instead of the index number.  It selects the next column!  The layout of the fields shown is as follows:

1. line number (read-only) dgvLineNum
2. Contact Name (editable) dgvContactName
3. Contact Phone (editable) dgvContactPhone
4. Contact Email (editable) dgvContactEmail

If I do the following to select the contact name on the new line:

```
grd.CurrentCell = grd.Rows[iNewLineNum - 1].Cells["dgvContactName"];
```

it selects (focuses) the next column dgvContactPhone.

If I do the following to select the contact phone on the new line:

```
grd.CurrentCell = grd.Rows[iNewLineNum - 1].Cells["dgvContactPhone"];
```

it selects the next column dgvContactEmail.

However, if I select:

```
grd.CurrentCell = grd.Rows[iNewLineNum - 1].Cells["dgvLineNum"];
```

It does select (readonly selection) the first column (the line number).

**Update #2**

I have placed a sample project with issue easily reproducible by pressing the tab key in the last column:

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=01137880750225210507

**Solution**

See solution below provided by LarsTech.  That solved it (return true instead of false in the ProcessDialogKey method):

...

```
LastTabReachedEventArgs ev = new LastTabReachedEventArgs();
ev.currentCol = currentCol;
ev.currentRow = currentRow;
OnLastTabReached(this, ev);
return true;
```

...

Comment: You made a new account?  Anyway, Cells[2] is a ReadOnly column according to your post.  I think you just want `if (currentCol == this.ColumnCount - 1( {` in your line, otherwise, you are only trying to check if the user is in the last column AND the last row, and in that position, the control is handing the tab-key processing back to the form to select the next control.  What is `[x]` in your code?

Comment: I updated the code above with current details.  x is the current line number (the last line).

Comment: Since this is such a strange issue, I uploaded two videos so you can visually see the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: All I can think is that the tab command is being executed twice??  (once to exit last column of current record and once after the new cell is selected)

Comment: The videos don't help — it looks like the first two columns are visible.  Here is my advice: create a new project, add a datagridview control to it, add your code to it, duplicate the problem with the smallest amount of code possible, edit your question with that.

Comment: Is there a command I am missing that most be executed in between the LastTabReachedEvent and the setting of grd.CurrentCell.. ?

Comment: LarsTech, please see update #3.  I have placed a sample project with issue easily reproducible by pressing the tab key in the last column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you question is why the column you are selecting is always picking the next cell over, that's because you aren't returning "true" in the ProcessDialogKey function.  You were returning "false", which tells the DataGridView control to continue with that key press, so it would logically "tab" over to the next cell.

```
LastTabReachedEventArgs ev = new LastTabReachedEventArgs();
ev.currentCol = currentCol;
ev.currentRow = currentRow;
OnLastTabReached(this, ev);
return true;
```

Comment: That was it!  Thank you very much for your help LarsTech.  Good job.